# how to use jquery datatables with ajax calls

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, flask, datatables

How to use ajax callbacks with jquery datatables i.e. call function on click?:

**THIS WORKS**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var table = $('#example').DataTable();

    $('#example tbody').on('click', 'tr', function () {
        var data = table.row( this ).data();
        alert( 'You clicked on '+data[0]+'\'s row' );
    } );
} );
```

replacing `alert( 'You clicked on '+data[0]+'\'s row' );` with Ajax call:

**DOES NOT WORK**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var table = $('#example').DataTable();

    $('#example tbody').on('click', 'tr', function () {
        var data = table.row( this ).data();
        //alert( 'You clicked on '+data[0]+'\'s row' );

         $.ajax({
                url: '/process',
                data: data[0],
                type: 'POST',
                success: function(response) {
                    $("#response_placeholder").html(response);
                },
                error: function(error) {
                    console.log(error);
                }
         });

    } );
} );
```

backend

```
#--app.py----

@app.route('/process', methods=['POST'])
def process_data():
    data =  request.form['data[0]'];
    print data
    return render_template('mypage.html', result=data)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try to use this.

```
 $('body').delegate('#example tbody tr','click' , function () {


} );
```

Delegate helps to add events on elements that get added to the dom after it has been loaded.

also it is handy to put the data in an object like this

```
data: {data: data[0]},
```

and the url should contain a extension probably

```
url: '/process.js', // or process.php depends on what extension it has.
```

and for standards you should define the 3 attributes that will be returned with error eg.

```
error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
```